# am trying to redirect the user but the this.$router.push('/') is giving me undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

am trying to redirect the user to the welcome page when the user logout and tot he home page, when the user logs back in..but the this.$router.push('/'), is giving me undefined.

Here is the code

```
handleAuthStateChanged: ({ commit }) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        commit("setLogin", true);
        console.log("login");
        //get current user details
        let userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(userId)
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists) {
              let currentUser = snapshot.data();
              commit("setUser", currentUser);
              console.log(currentUser);
            } else {
              // snapshot.data() will be undefined in this case
              console.log("No such document!");
            }
          });
        this.$router.push("/");
      } else {
        console.log("logout");
        commit("setLogin", false);
        commit("setUser", null);

        this.$router.replace("/welcome");
      }
    });
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ScNz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `this` within the `onAuthStateChanged` function scope, which means `this` inside the scope will refers to the own function (since you are using arrow function), not Vue instance.

This wont work:

```js
handleAuthStateChanged: ({ commit }) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        ...
        // `this` is not a Vue instance
        this.$router.push("/");
    })
}
```

You need to make a variable that refer to Vue instance first outside the scope so you can call it inside the function scope, for example:

```js
handleAuthStateChanged: ({ commit }) => {
    const self = this;
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        ...
        // `this` is not a Vue instance, but `self` is
        self.$router.push("/");
    })
}
```

Or don't use arrow function since `this` inside an arrow function refers to the function it self, for example:

```js
handleAuthStateChanged: ({ commit }) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        ...
        // `this` is a Vue instance 
        this.$router.push("/");
    })
}
```